# ¿Cómo formatear el código en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, xml, text

¿Qué atajo de teclado o comando se debe utilizar para formatear el código? Ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TITLE"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Y que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: En la documentación de Android Studio tienes toda la información necesaria. En este [enlace](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html), en la sección 'Estilo y formato' tienes información específica sobre tu pregunta. Mientras que en este otro [enlace](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html) tienes todos los atajos de teclado del IDE.

Answer (score 6):

Para Identar codigo intenta con:

Windows:

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Mac:

> <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Linux:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Para ver mas opciones de combinaciones de tecla en Android Studio puedes acceder a:

```
File->Settings->Keymap
```

Comment: Como punto adicional a tu respuesta: aquí estan los [Comandos clave](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html#KeyCommands) y aquí están los comandos completos para usuarios de [Windows / Linux](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) y para usuarios de [Mac](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf)